# Dumping mongodbdatabase using meteor locally

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I need to know how can dump the mongo db database locally using meteor.The database 'test' resides the folder name 'reaction'  is  dumping to another folder in  same drive.How it is possible?Please help.Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you just trying to delete all the documents in your database so it is completely empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to dump the database use the command

```
mongodump -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 -d meteor
```

After issuing this command a new folder "dump" will be created with your data.